# Cocoa Display many items in Table View

Tags: c, macos, cocoa, freepascal

i start to develop my company application from Windows to Mac.
The first thing i need to solve is create a window to display data, the current windows table is use custom grid, and now move to Mac i don't known what is the best components to do that.
The table requires :

> - Can display ~1.000.000 or more items (x14 column or more)
> - each cell can be custom paint (with different font,color, or maybe display custom image)
> - i can update each cell every time i got the data

in 1 application user may open 10 or more table like that so the performance is what i care about.

What is the components i should use for this kind of application ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [NSTableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nstableview_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Take a look at [Table View Programming Guide for Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i)